# App Icon disappear from action bar

Tags: android

I am developing an application for two languages (english & arabic),
I noticed that the app icon disappears from action bar when changing the language to Arabic.

I found out the solution by trial and error, this was due redundant styles.xml that was included in both folders **values/styles.xml** & **values-ar/styles.xml**,
can anyone can explain why this happened?

Also another question:
I noticed that the icon app and app title are aligned to the left of the action bar, How can i change the alignment to be to the right, upon changing the language to Arabic?
Cant I do that by using certain Theme in case of Arabic

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have linked the appearance of icon to translate some text and is giving you problems in the application. It happened something similar and was due to this.

Hope it helps.